# ssrs report collapsible/expandable grouping

Tags: reporting-services

I need to create collapsible ssrs report, please refer below.

Here is the sample of the report:

`Header1(parentgroup)    Header2
 AAA                     BBB
                         CCC
                         DDD`

supposed output

`Header1(parentgroup)
AAA --as header
BBB ]
CCC ] -- collapsible
DDD ]`

Answer (score 0):

Right click the cell you want to have the +/- control in and click TextBox Properties. Note the value of the "Name" field. Exit that and click any cell in the table. You will see the grey column and row bumpers appear around the table. Right click the bumper for the row you want to collapse and select "Row Visibility..."

If you want it to be collapsed by default, set the radio button to hide. Then click the "Display can be toggled by this report item" checkbox. In the dropdown, select the TextBox name you noted above.

Run the report and you will be able to expand and collapse that row.

Note that if you "Show" by default, the button to collapse the row will be a + and the button to expand it will be a -. I have not figured out a way to fix this and believe it is a bug in SSRS.